# IncludeInvocationHeader not working with Start-Transcript

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell

I'm working with a script that parses out a Windows Powershell transcript. The script is dependent on the ...

```
**********************
Command start time: 20170426095605
**********************
```

...headers that appear in the transcript before each command when `Start-Transcript` is used with the `-IncludeInvocationHeader` switch.

However, now that I'm testing this script on a windows 7 and Windows 2012 (2012 ver. 6.2 build 9200) Start-Transcript is telling me `-IncludeInvocationHeader` is not valid.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Start-Transcript -Path C:\Users\(snip)\PowerShell_transcript.txt -IncludeInvocationHeader
Start-Transcript : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'IncludeInvocationHeader'.
At line:1 char:91
+ ... pt.newfile.txt -IncludeInvocationHeader
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Transcript], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartTranscriptCommand

PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Was this a new addition? An outdated switch? Do I need to enable it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It Looks like this is related to the Powershell version. The switch is not available in PSv3 or less. I believe it's available in v4. It is tested as available in v5.